# excel formula to look at only 10 digits of the cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, lookup

I want to look at only the first 10 digits of the cells.
If the cells that are in column C equals to the cells in column G (but in another tab), then I want the result from column H(from same tab of G).
I tried with the VLOOKUP but it gives me the error.
The total number of digits in the cell is 11, so I don't if it is easier to write to only look at first 10 or to say to not consider the 1st from right.

Example:
I have 11234567890 in one cell (C2) and 11234567891 in another (G2) with related item description(H2), I want have the same description for the item in G2 even if the last digit does not match.

WORKING FORMULA:
=XLOOKUP(Left(C2,10),Left(Tab2!G:G,10),Tab2!H:H,"")

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the above data/column is in the same Sheet. Do :

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(C1&"",LEFT(G:G,10),0))
```

And press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, to and it will (automatically) become :

```
{=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(C1&"",LEFT(G:G,10),0))}
```

as it is entered as array formula. The original tutorial (which explains much2 better than me), is on the link shared in the comment.

Please share if it works/understandable/not.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!
The formula itself works, but what if I don't know where the matching cell is in the column G?
For example, it only gives me 2 results because the cells have the same position, but for all the other cells that I do not know where the "matching" serial number is, what kind of function should I include? Vlookup? Index and Match?

Comment: y not create another column beside G2, with `=LEFT(G2,10)` the use [index match](https://exceljet.net/index-and-match) ? afaik, xlookup, vlookup & index-match only do exact match.

Comment: (if it works, I'll post it as the solution)

Comment: got it : https://exceljet.net/formula/partial-match-with-numbers-and-wildcard & https://exceljet.net/formula/partial-match-with-vlookup

Comment: Thank you! It actually worked with the previous formula you gave me, combined with Xlookup!

Comment: U r welcomed. (If u don't mind) appreciate if u can edit this post and include your (working) formula.. ( I'm don't have 356 version installed to test/guess how that final function look like).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another formula, you may also have a check.
`=IF(C2="","",IFNA(LOOKUP(1,0/FIND(LEFT(C2,10),Sheet2!G$2:G$11,1),Sheet2!H$2:H$11),""))`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `VLOOKUP()` in the following manner:

```
=VLOOKUP(LEFT(C1,3),LEFT(Tab2!G:H,10),2,FALSE)
```

It has an advantage over the equivalent `XLOOKUP()` in that using the full columns as you presented means you hit a limit on the cells actually checked due to the function only handling "so many and no more" characters when it builds the internal array string from the G column's entries. `VLOOKUP()` has a similar kind of limit in building that array but it doesn't care that the array string ends... badly... except by chance.

That bad ending to the array built for the values is why your `XLOOKUP()` did not work.

So nice and simple.

You used the Excel-2010 tag although you use `XLOOKUP()`, and so must have a far more recent version. Maybe some of your users have some Excel 2010 amongst them? If there IS a need to work in Excel 2010, can still use the `VLOOKUP()` directly from here. No `{CSE }` entry needed.